# MongoDB + Nodejs : Increment a specific value of an array in a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, increment

my MongoDB documents have the following structure:

```
{ _id : 'some_ID',
  matrix:  [[0,0,0][0,0,0][0,0,0]]
}
```

I'd like my NodeJS server to increment the ***second value*** of the ***second array*** in ***matrix***, given a specific ID.

i.e I 'd like to have:

```
{ _id : 'some_ID',
  matrix:  [[0,0,0][0,1,0][0,0,0]]
}
```

I wrongly tried:

```
db.collection('myCollection').update({ _id  :  'some_ID'  },
                                     { $inc :  { matrix[1][1] : 1 } }
                                    );
```

Any guess on the right way to do that ?

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and specify array indexes to increment the value:

```
db.collection('myCollection').update({ _id: 'some_ID' },
                                     { $inc: { "matrix.1.1": 1 } }
                                    );
```